# is it blender or my svg

Tags: modeling

So I have an SVG file I exported from illustrator and when I import into blender nothing shows up, but a collection is created with nothing in it. So I went back to adobe and added a shape over the image and saved it as a new SVG. Imported it all over again and this time only the new shape I just added will show. Did I do something wrong with blender, or is it the SVG file?

Here is my SVG file: http://www.filedropper.com/200925abbottbinaxnowwebinarforhhandhospicevf-20

Can someone test it with your blender to let me know if it's my blender that is the issue or if you see my problem too, and then it's something wrong with the SVG file somehow.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely the file.  You can use the [W3C Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/check) to validate an SVG file, since it is in markup format.  Running the validator shows 5 errors as shown in the image below

[image: SVG file validation errors]

Comment: Inkscape opened it just fine. The file is just a PNG image embedded in an SVG wrapper anyway, except for the polygon at the end. OP might as well just use PNG.

Comment: So you are saying that the SVG is in some markup format and that's my issue? I'll try to look that up and see how to solve that if you think that's all. Thank you. Also, I just clicked on your link to check the file for myself, and I couldn't find anywhere that it said anything about markup format. How did you come to that conclusion, so I may find that out for myself in any future files.

Comment: @RonJensen I was told to use SVG in the past because it will be easier to turn that into a mesh instead of using image as plain for the import.

Comment: @AlexWillis21 SVG is a complex and feature rich file format. It can contain splines, polygons and other numeric data that can be turned into meshes. It can also contain bitmap layers, which are just plain old images.

Comment: @AlexWillis21 SVG might be easier to convert into a mesh if you're using a vector graphic, since it consists of curves drawn between points - like a 3D mesh is built of vertices connected with edges. But a pixel image doesn't work like that, not even if you save it as a SVG.

Comment: SVG Viewer opens it fine as well.  It looks like Blender's SVG reader is stricter than other applications.  And yes, SVG is some markup format and that's your issue.